# Facebook PHP SDK v4: AccessToken->getExpiresAt() does not return correct time

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I use the following code to get expiration time of Access Token:

```
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
$token_obj = new AccessToken($token);
$expires_at = $token_obj->getExpiresAt();
echo 'Expires At: ' .$expires_at . PHP_EOL;

$info = $token_obj->getInfo();
$info = $info->asArray();
echo 'Expires At (Info): ' . $info['expires_at'] . PHP_EOL;
```

which outputs:

```
Expires At: 0
Expires At (Info): 1438214400 // which is 2015-07-30 08:00:00
```

Why does the `getExpiresAt()` return incorrect result?

p.s.

- as `getInfo()` causes some time to load, I am trying to avoid it
- using Facebook PHP SDK v4

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't saved the expiration timestamp value when getting the access token, then you must call `getInfo()` to get that value.

As you manually create an access token instance, I guess you have that value in a database. Then a solution would be to save the `expires_at` value in a new field when a user grant your app, it's returned with the new access token.

Comment: I see. Apart from the expiration value, is there any other field that I should save apart from access token & the expiration timestamp? Read from other answers, I should save a token exchange code as well, in order to renew the token for long-lived ones...

Comment: You don't. See [the doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#refreshtokens)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I read that before, and  it did mention storing a code for later use, at the exchange user long-lived token phase. So I am quite confused on the token exchange concept.